# Make debug kit use Memcache

Tags: php, cakephp, configuration, memcached

I have configured CakePHP 2.1 to use Memcache .
But debugkit insists on using Filecache. 
Is there any way to make it use Memcache instead ?

There seem to be no mention of a way to configure this at

- http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42880/docs-configuration
- https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after interacting with the author of the plugin.
It was quite simple as I imagined, It just wasn't given in the documentation.
The answer can be found at this [link](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit/blob/master/Controller/Component/ToolbarComponent.php#L263), the [hint](https://twitter.com/mark_story/statuses/185752970640621569) was given by the author himself.

So we can set the config in `core.php` like so

```
/**
 * Configure Debug kit to use Memcache instead of File cache
 */
Cache::config('debug_kit', array(
    'engine' => $engine,
    'prefix' => $prefix . 'debug_kit',
    'path' => CACHE . 'debug_kit' . DS,
    'serialize' => ($engine === 'File'),
    'duration' => $duration
));
```

Where `$engine` can be any caching engine.

PS : I have requested the author to add it to the documentation